# How To Add Title For Each Page In Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade, laravel-5.7

In my laravel website all pages having same title meta but how to  make different title  for each page please tell me.

this is my code for dynamic showing in all the pages

```
<title>{{setting('site.title')}} | {{setting('site.description')}}  @if(isset($data->title)) {{$data->title}} @endif</title>
```

file name is `layouts/app.blade.php`

Answer (score 15):

Inside your `app.blade.php`, in the head section.
change:

```php
<title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
```

to:

```php
<title>@yield('title')</title>
```

You can choose any name/title that seems fitting.
For other `views.blade.php` pages,(extending `app.blade.php`) you can add a title this way:

```php
@section('title','My Title')
```

this comes after `@extends('layouts.app')`

Answer (score 11):

You can specify different title for different views.

In you common header file make your title like this:

```
<title>@yield('page_title', 'Default Title')</title>
```

Then in your view file change the title to whatever you want it to be set in following way:

```
@section('page_title')
    {{ "Your Title" }}
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply inside your app.blade.php
Put this:   @yield('title')

In other pages just extend the layout and  put the new title at the this section

@extends('layoutWhateverYouNamedIt')

@section('title')
Type your title here
@endsection

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `app.blade.php`,

```
<head>
  @yield('title')
  ... // other scripts
</head>
```

For other pages which user app.blade.php you can use it like after extending `app.blade.php` :

```
@section('title')
    <title> Your Page Title Here  </title>
@endsection`
```

Hope it helps. happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

in your controller

```
    public function aboutUs()
    {
        //page title
        $title = 'Project | About Us';
        return view('project.about_us', compact('title'));
    }
```

for your view page

```
<title>{{ $title }}</title>
```